# How to combine my seed jobs in Jenkins Job DSL?

Tags: jenkins, credentials, dsl

I am trying to create a job in Jenkins that has an 'Authentication Token' as a Build Trigger (so it will do a build on a git push).  I'm defining everything using Job DSL, i.e. without any manual configuration of any jobs.

The Authentication Token is defined in Jenkins as a Credential, as I don't want this token hard-coded, and checked into SCM.

The following works: it defines a *bootstrap* job which in turn defines a *seed* job with the credential bound to an environment variable; the *seed* job then defines the actual build job (which is the important one - the one I want to be able to trigger using the token).

**bootstrap.groovy:**

```
/* 
 * Create the seed job, and bind the credential to it, for use downstream
 */

def seed_dsl = readFileFromWorkspace('./jobs/seed.groovy')

job('seed')
{
    wrappers {
        credentialsBinding {
            string ('AUTH_TOKEN','my-trigger-token')
        }
    }

     steps {
        dsl {
            text(seed_dsl)
        }
    }
}

/* Queue the job */
queue('seed')
```

**seed.groovy:**

```
/* 
 * Create the build job, and associate the authentication token with it
 */

job('My Useful Build Job') {

    authenticationToken(AUTH_TOKEN)

    steps {
        shell ('echo Do something useful like build my app here')
    }
}
```

But, now I have a chain of **3** jobs: *bootstrap* >  *seed* > *My Useful Build Job*.  This has a bit of a bad smell imho - it's unwieldly, clutters up Jenkins, and is hard to explain.

Can this be simplified down, to remove an intermediate job - i.e. I want to be able to create a job with an Authentication token defined as a credential, but in two steps: *seed* > *My Useful Build Job*

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I raise a enhancement request for Jenkins to support credentials for authenticationToken: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56802

Comment: No I never solved it, thanks for the update